# Why C# Language Specification doesn't mention about pointer types?

Tags: c#, pointers, types

When I was reading `C# Language Specification`, I have noticed that there is nothing about `Pointer types` in [Types section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664634%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).Specification is mentioning about `Pointer types` in [another section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx) but I'm just wondering why they didn't mention about pointers in `Types` section? `C#` definitely supports pointer types so is there a technical reason for not mentioning about them in the `Types` section?

Comment: So you have found the documentation you are looking for, but are asking the community why the specification is organized in the way that it is?  I'm not sure what you're problem really is and either way such a question is a poor fit for SO.

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess, it may be because they are unsafe and their use should be avoided at (almost) all costs.

Comment: @Ginosaji I'd strongly disagree with that - pointer types definitely have their place - they're rarely needed but to 'avoid them at all cost' is wrong. They can be used to great effect (when used in the right situation). Any tool can be misused, just like pointers.

Comment: @xxbbcc: The very few situations in which unsafe code may be desirable or even necessary are why I included the "(almost)" disclaimer.

Comment: @Ginosaji you're right, you did say that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, starting from:

- The first link points to specification from 2003. It's kind of old.
- the second link is not a specification, it's a programming guide?

Pointers are mentioned in [**C# 5** specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx), in **4. Types** section. Right in the introduction to this chapter:

> A third category of types, pointers, is available only in unsafe code. This is discussed further in **§18.2**.

Rules for pointer types are much different then for value and reference type, and I would assume that's the reason why there is entire chapter titled **18. Unsafe code**.

Comment: interesting.but why the specification in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645596(v=vs.71).aspx) link is not **up-to-date**, it comes first in the google.I didn't choose 2003

Comment: @Selman22 I don't know. You should blame google for serving outdated data as the best search result, not MSDN for showing historical data (yes, there are people still using C# 2.0).

Answer (score 2):

A pointer type is not a special kind of type as the CLR understands it, it's just a pointer to another concrete type, or at least a memory address in the case of void*.

Apart from the fact that the CLR gives you more control, and demands that your code is trusted and manages its own security; there is no difference between a string and a string*; after indirection they're both System.String.

A pointer type isn't a type, it's a pointer to a type; It's just that the CLR drops all of its safety checks and assumes that you know what you're doing.

I guess it's worth noting that anything that's passed 'by-ref' (ie Classes as method parameters) are pointers in .Net anyway; they're just protected by the CLR.

Comment: You're making the same fundamental problem though - they are a type in as much as they're a type of referencing something but they're not a 'Type' as they're not something that f.ex inherits System.Object.

Comment: Well, fact that they don't inherit System.Object doesn't proof that they are not a type. you can still do `typeof(IntPtr)` and you'll get `Type` instance. They are just different category of types, as stated in spec.

Comment: From the ECMA CLI Spec: "Pointer types, function pointer types, and
value types are not object types." (I.8.9)  Pointers are not types in the sense that they are representable as `System.Type`s.  They have no `MethodTable`, they are typed according to the object to which they point, but "values of a pointer type are not objects... it is not possible, given a value of a pointer type, to determine its exact type." (I.8.9.2)

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be (without knowing this for a fact) that pointer types are only available in unsafe contexts (this is mentioned in the MSDN pages you linked to).

The documentation for built-in types is likely for the most common, general use which doesn't include unsafe scenarios (which are rarely needed in C#). I'm only guessing, though, and there could be another reason.

Comment: Actually, anytime you pass something by reference in C#, you're using a pointer whether you know it or not.

Comment: @RussC I know - I did a lot of unsafe coding with C#.

Comment: Cool :) But you don't need to do unsafe coding to be using pointers in C#, you just often don't think of what you're using as being pointers. I thought I'd point out the difference as it's something that newer C# developers don't always get.

Comment: @RussC - ah, ok, I missed that point completely. :) Thanks for mentioning that and you're right about it.

Comment: @RussC, you are using a reference, not a pointer.   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/07/references-and-pointers-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 0):

May be because pointers in C# are not verified by CLR and this is mentioned in documentation as well that C# by default does not support pointer arithmetic.

To me it makes more sense to keep Managed and Unmanaged specifications separately in documentation.

You would have already read given link but still it makes more sense when you read this page.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx